# Adding Realm android to flutter project not working

Tags: android, realm, flutter

I am trying to add Realm-android to my flutter project. I have added gradle dependencies as per the Realm documentation, but I still don't see realm packages in my android code, when I try to extend classes with Realm classes. I also tried gradle sync,  gradlew clean assemble, but still no fix.

Gradle files: /android/build.gradle

```
   repositories {
        ...
        jcenter()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.0.0'
}
```

/android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use Realm from Dart.

Comment: True, can not use it directly from Dart, what I am trying to test is install it on the Android side as a normal android app will be using it using Realm-java, and use flutter channel to send and receive signals.

Comment: Hmm, interesting hypothesis,  either way I'm a bit surprised that it's not getting added. Considering it seems to be regular `com.android.application`, it should work. Have you tried to apply it after `flutter.gradle`?

Comment: Exactly my expectation, but it is not working ;( I tried changing "apply plugin" statement position and added at the end of file, but still wont work, either app/build.gradle file that flutter generates, is the root cause, or I might be making some silly mistake. I tried creating new pure android project and added same config as per the realm docs and everything worked, so my guess is flutter's generated app/build.gradle is most probably the reason.

Comment: Silly reason indeed, I had imported flutters project root folder in Android Studio, when I tried by importing android only folder (flooter_root/android), everything started working fine and Intellisense started picking Realm classes also, Now not sure add this as ans or should delete question.

Comment: Ehh, not enough Flutter questions out there, just answer your own question with an answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, it was silly reason causing this issue. 
Instead of importing flutter project root folder in Android studio, import only android (flutter_project_root_dir/android) specific folder into Android Studio. This fixed the issue for me.

Hope this saves some time of others facing similar issue.

Comment: were you then able to use realm in flutter?

Comment: Yes, I mean it was just integration of native realm and flutter, then I was able to save & read data using native realm code + flutter platform channel. I sent the data I wanted to save over flutter platform channel and then native realm code in JAVA performed the saving/querying etc.

Comment: Thats nice, and did the auto sync mechanism work that way?

Comment: Did not check that, but in my opinion, it being just plain Android native realm setup handling the db specific part of app, I guess, all features that work with normal plain Android app, will work with this setup too!